# correct usage of order by while using union to concat multiple queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

this is the code the result is not ordered

```
(select concat (name,"(",left(OCCUPATION,1),")") 
 from OCCUPATIONS 
 order by name asc
) union 
(select concat ("there are a total of ",count(OCCUPATION)," ",OCCUPATION, "s.") 
 from OCCUPATIONS 
 group by OCCUPATION 
 order by count(OCCUPATION) asc,OCCUPATION asc
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGZQK.png)

Comment: What ordering you need to follow ?

Comment: I assume that you want to order by occupation count first then the name of people with that occupation (or vice-versa), is that correct?